# ifelse grep gsub recycled leaving remainder warning, R

Tags: string, data-manipulation

I'd like to replace all city name strings which contain parenthesis to be what is contained in the parenthesis but I am doing it incorrectly. Please advise

`df$City<-ifelse(grep("[(]",df$City),gsub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", df$City),df$City)`

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Supplied 53 items to be assigned to 9243 items of column 'City' (recycled leaving remainder of 21 items).
```

sample data dput:

```
structure(list(Column = c(6648L, 9343L, 45L, 2525L, 344L, 345L, 
5138L, 6649L, 346L, 4058L, 2732L, 2910L, 6199L, 6647L, 2526L), 
    City = c("Guangzhou", "Cairo", "Jakarta", "Tokyo", "New Delhi", 
    "Kolkata (Calcutta)", "Dhaka", "Shanghai", "Mumbai (Bombay)", 
    "Manila", "Seoul", "Mexico City", "São Paulo", "Beijing", 
    "Kinki M.M.A. (Osaka)"), Area = c(16353.06, 7371, 5991.63, 
    5291.25, 2499, 4559.56, 2739, 3272.56, 1625.94, 2250.44, 
    2498.25, 2440, 2248, 2997, 3211.63), builtup75 = c(507, 908.5, 
    2649.5, 2206.5, 377.5, 503, 96.5, 415, 369, 448.5, 540.5, 
    813, 1295.5, 1107.5, 2028.5), builtup90 = c(1978.5, 1626, 
    3183, 3541, 889.5, 700, 256, 888.5, 659, 838.5, 877, 1219.5, 
    1659, 1949, 2276.5), builtup00 = c(2985.5, 1748, 3491, 3641, 
    1002.5, 758, 311, 1193, 720.5, 879, 991.5, 1313, 1678.5, 
    2048.5, 2318.5), builtup15 = c(3662, 2019.5, 3864, 3858, 
    1184.5, 843.5, 498, 1737, 820, 929, 1078.5, 1390, 1695.5, 
    2217.5, 2340.5), population75 = c(14242521L, 16298368L, 11389772L, 
    23244360L, 10171291L, 16738412L, 5079023L, 5322084L, 12860636L, 
    5448606L, 13229878L, 13886608L, 11070712L, 3871802L, 14607758L
    ), population90 = c(24301021L, 24107176L, 19735267L, 28009882L, 
    15457636L, 21280466L, 10156383L, 10505847L, 16665836L, 12578608L, 
    17573203L, 17245381L, 15316139L, 7939414L, 16079851L), population00 = c(32343410L, 
    29105701L, 25682202L, 30621222L, 19849364L, 24109752L, 15452476L, 
    15298806L, 19420018L, 17136180L, 19522076L, 18887189L, 17645195L, 
    11868756L, 16457563L), population15 = c(46036352L, 37839851L, 
    36397542L, 33732663L, 27634561L, 26864480L, 24833278L, 24669093L, 
    23401888L, 22400343L, 22127687L, 20089749L, 20021851L, 19901960L, 
    16521446L), UID = c(12827L, 3560L, 12584L, 13701L, 6542L, 
    9612L, 9953L, 13141L, 6400L, 13542L, 13127L, 157L, 1204L, 
    11054L, 13577L)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just decided to use OpenRefine for this because the data was needed to be edited more carefully as some of the values in the parenthesis were more valuable than others